# How to update data in Observable in Angular? rxjs

Tags: angular, rxjs

I am working on learning Angular and Typescript.
Now, I want to do this：

1. get user list from web api

```
public list$:Observable<{id:string,name:string,like:number}[]> = new Observable()

ngOnInit(): void {
   this.getData()
}

getData(){
   this.list$ = this.service.getUserList()
}
```

2. render user list

```
<ul>
  <li *ngFor="let item of list$ | async">
    <input (ngModelChange) = "changeName($event,item.id)">
    ....
  </li>
</ul>
```

3. change the user name by id

```
  async changeName(newName:string,id:string){
    const res = await this.service.changeName(newName,id).toPromise()
    if(res.success){
       // How to update this.list$ , without send a new request     
       // just like this:
       // this.userList = this.userList.map(i=>i.id === id ? { ...i, name:newName } : i)
    }
  }
```

1. Is this something that can be done?
2. If yes, is it something that SHOULD be done, or is there a better way to accomplish what I am trying to do?

   thinks!!!!

Comment: Subscribe it in the component, do your thing, render it. Unsubscribe in the onDestroy() method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your code to send `item` to `changeName` method and modify the `item.name=newName` inside `changeName` method after successful API update response. As we are passing the reference of the item we should see the name updated properly.

```
<ul>
  <li *ngFor="let item of list$ | async">
    <input (ngModelChange) = "changeName($event,item)">
    ....
  </li>
</ul>
```

And script

```
async changeName(newName:string,item:any){
    const res = await this.service.changeName(newName, item.id).toPromise()
    if(res.success){
       item.name=newName;
    }
  }
```

Comment:  thanks

Comment: @kkerwin Please upvote if you feel it helped you so that it will helps other and also motivates my work.

Answer (score 0):

While the solution works. I don't think it's the recommended way to do.

The reason is, you are updating the data manually - set the name to signal/notify for the view to update.

With Observer/Observable - reactive programming, we want the view to update automatically whenever the data change.

The solution for this is to use [Subject](https://rxjs.dev/api/index/class/Subject), where every time you change something, the Subject will push that change to its subscribers

Comment: [https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-c2pzt8?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts](example)
hello,
When i use Subject，I can't get "the old data(the data from web api )", So i used BehaviorSubject , because i can use `BehaviorSubject.value ` get the data. Is there anything wrong with me doing this？
Can you give me an example? thanks!

Comment: True. In case you want "the old data", BehaviorSubject is needed. You learnt it quick, great!